# Check to See if Field Exists

Tags: templating, matrix

When looping through a matrix, is there aquick way to check whether or not the block has a particular field (not if the field is empty, but if the field exists at all).

I have a matrix with ~20 block types, 12 or so have a field called blockTitle. For in-page nav, I'd like to loop through all the blocks and just output blockTitle for those that do have it. I could do this with a conditional for block.type, but am wondering if there's a simpler check (in case we add more block types in the future, don't want to have to update the conditional every time).

Using {% if block.blockTitle %} will kick back "Craft\MatrixBlockModel and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "blockTitle"." for block types without that field, so that's a no go.

Tks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This should work:

```
{% if block['blockTitle'] is defined %}
    // Do your thing
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to set custom field parameters on Matrix block queries (→ [Craft 2.3 release notes](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2615)). And looking for non empty fields is possible with `:nonempty:` (also not documented but mentioned in the [2.0 release notes](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2524)).

```
{% set blocksWithTitle = entry.myMatrixField.myTitleField(':notempty:') %}

{% for block in blocksWithTitle %}
    {{ block.myTitleField }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

The most reliable method i've found to test if a matrix field is defined is using the `length` twig filter:

```
{% if entry.myMatrixField | length %}
  {% for block in entry.myMatrixField %}
    <p>Matrix blocks here.</p>
  {% endfor %}
{% else %}
  <p>Matrix not defined.</p>
{% endif %}
```

More on this in the Craft CMS docs [here](https://craftcms.com/docs/matrix-fields#getting-the-total-number-of-blocks).

Comment: I believe that `entry.myMatrixField.first()` (or `entry.myMatrixField.one()` in Craft v3) is more efficient, because it doesn't have to count them all up.